# Returning a Structure of a structure and Int

Tags: c, struct, return

I am trying to use these two structures to return a struct to my main where I will then call other functions like sorting and printing.

I am also getting  `error: request for member ‘vehicles’ in something not a structure or union`

Along with the same error but for `error: request for member ‘count’ in something, not a structure or union`

These errors are corresponding with

```
value.count = count;
 value.vehicles = vehicles;
```

These are my structs I am using.

```
struct data{

    char *model;
    float engineSize;
    int cost;
    char *color;
};

struct values{

    struct data vehicles;
    int count;
};
```

This is the sort readFile function that will be returning the structs

```
struct values * readFile(){

    FILE *fp;
    int c;
    int count = 0;
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;

    fp = fopen("hw3.data", "r");


    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){
        if(c == '\n'){
            count++;
        }

    }

    if (feof(fp)){

        rewind(fp);

        struct data *vehicles = malloc((sizeof(struct data))* count);


        count = 0;
        char *token = NULL;
        while (getline(&line, &len, fp)!= -1){

            printf("%s", line);

            token = strtok(line,  " ");

            vehicles[count].model = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
            strcpy(vehicles[count].model, token);

            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            vehicles[count].engineSize = atof(token);

            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            vehicles[count].cost = atoi(token);

            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            vehicles[count].color = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
            strcpy(vehicles[count].color, token);

            free(line);
            line = NULL;
            len = 0;

        }
        struct values *value = malloc(sizeof(struct values));
    value.vehicles = vehicles;
    value.count = count;
    return value;
    }
```

This is the main function that I am going to be using to call the readFile function, sort functions, and print functions.

```
int main(){

    int check = 1;
    int input, n;

    while (check == 1){

        printf("Enter a value corresponding to a option on the menu below\n\n");

        printf("1. Sort data by the float value & print high to low\n");
        printf("2. Sort data by the float value & print low to high\n");
        printf("3. Sort data by the int value & print high to low\n");
        printf("4. Sort data by the int value & print low to high\n");
        printf("5. Exit\n\n");

        printf("Enter a value corresponding to the above menu\n");
        scanf("%d", &input);

        struct values *value = readFile();
        struct data *vehicles = value.vehicles;
        n = value.count;

        if(input == 1 || input == 2 || input == 3 || input == 4 || input == 5){

            if (input == 5){

                exit(0);

            }if (input == 1){

                //sort float high to low
                //bubbleSortFloats(vehicles[], 0);


            }if (input == 2){

                //sort float low to high
                //bubbleSortFloats(vehicles[], 1);


            }if (input == 3){


                //sort int value high to low
                //bubbleSortInts(vehicles[], 0);



            }if (input == 4){

                //sort int value low to high
                //bubbleSortInts(vehicles[], 1);


            }

        }else{

            printf("Enter a correct value for the menus above\n\n" );
        }



    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be

```
value->vehicles = vehicles
```

`value` is a pointer to the memory of the `struct values` structure instance. Dereference the pointer first to get to the structure instance. Compiler complained because you tried to get the `vehicles` attribute from a pointer variable which is neither a struct nor a union - it is *a pointer to struct values* instance. Same will be the case for other member `value->count = count;`

Keep in mind that `value->count` is same as `(*value).count`. A shorthand notation for this is arrow notation. `->`.

- `value` — is a pointer to the `struct values` variable.
- `*value` — is `struct values` variable.
- `(*value).count` — is a member variable of the struct instance `struct values`.
- `values->count` — same as that of the last line.

Comment: okay, so you are talking to dereference by just turning struct values *value to struct values value?

Comment: @JeffreyHennen.: I dont get what you asked but you have to dereference the pointer `value` -- `(*value).vehicles` or `value->vehicles`. That's it

Comment: @JeffreyHennen.: Hope it helped? In case of doubt ask question